# Why does an array of pointers initializes itself when function finishes?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

My weekend assignment was to make a function that gets an array of integers and the size of the array, and creates an array of pointers so that the pointers will be sorted using bubble sort (without changing the original array).

While debugging I found out that it works just fine, but when the function goes back to main() the pointers array gets initialized and everything's gone.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void pointerSort(int arr[], int size, int* pointers[]);
void swap(int a, int b);
void main()
{
    int arr[5]={7,2,5,9,4};
    int size = 5;
    int* pointers[5];

    pointerSort(arr, size, pointers);

    for (int i = 0; i < 5 ; i++)
        cout << *pointers[i] << endl;
}
void pointerSort(int arr[], int size, int* pointers[])
{
    int j, i;
    bool change = true;

    pointers = new int*[size];
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        pointers[i] = &arr[i];

    i = 0;
    j = 1;
    while (i <= size-1 && change == true)
    {
        change = false;
        for (i = 0; i < size-j; i++)
        {
            if (*pointers[i] > *pointers[i+1])
            {
                swap(pointers[i], pointers[i+1]);
                change = true;
            }
        }
        j++;
    }
}
void swap(int&a, int&b)
{
    int temp;

    temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}
```

Comment: Your `swap` function does nothing.

Comment: swap() is not useful, its passby value, do pass by address.

Comment: right, forgot the &, but it has nothing to do with the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
pointers = new int*[size];
```

At this point `pointers` is already an array of pointers, no allocation is needed.

After this line `pointers` **IS NO LONGER THE ARRAY IN YOUR MAIN FUNCTION**.

**This is why your function is failing**, because you are reassigning the array to which `pointers` is pointing to. The original array ISNT getting reinitialized, its just ignored throughout the entire code.

It is also a [memory leak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak) as ATaylor mentions, since you do not delete the allocated space, and cannot delete the space after the function finishes.

To fix everything: just remove the above line.

Comment: @ATaylor yup true and proper leak, since you lose all reference to the allocated memory.

Comment: I understand, should I `delete [] pointers` before I allocate it inside the function?

Comment: @Quaker pls refer to my answer. The allocation is unnecessary, and indeed your problem, just remove it to fix it.

Comment: @Quaker and to avoid memory leaks, you should delete allocated memory after it is used. or use smart pointers instead of pointers and smart containers like `vector` instead of handwritten dynamic arrays

Comment: @KarthikT, I haven't learned using `vector` yet, so I guess I'm not allowed to. But after deleting the allocation, where do I have a leak?

Comment: @Quaker the allocation line is the leaking line, if you delete it, you no longer have a leak either

Comment: Thank you very much! Assuming I can't give the function an array of pointers at the size of the integers array, should I  then `delete [] ponters;`?

Comment: @Quaker with `int* pointers[5];` you already have everything you need - an array of 5 `int*`s. Only if you get memory with `new` do you have to `delete`.  So no.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22232/discussion-between-quaker-and-karthik-t)